# Error trying to fetch access token from Spotify API using Axios

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, spotify

I'm working on a project with Vue using the Spotify API and get stuck trying to get the access token. I'm using axios to make the request but every time I get a 400 status from the server.

This is the way I'm doing it, I have the request inside an action in my Vuex store and I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

```
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        params: {
          grant_type: 'authorization_code',
          code: payload.code,
          redirect_uri: process.env.VUE_APP_REDIRECT_URI
        },
        headers: { 
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID + ':' + process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET).toString('base64')),
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
        },
        json: true
        })
        .then((response) => {
            //handle success
            resolve(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            //handle error
            reject(error);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `data` instead of `params`.

I think `data` is for the POST body and `params` is for query string parameters.

[Axios Cheat Sheet](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index)

You should inspect the request to see what you're sending and then compare that to what you should be sending.